# Cauchy's integral formula for different closed curve.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I know that there is a formula called Cauchy's integral formula for entire function $f$

$$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{f(s)}{s-a}ds$$

Where $C$ is a closure of a disc.

> Is it possible that we consider different type of closed curve for example rectangle, and by special integral on this curve that we would calculate value of $f$ at any point inside this curve?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Actually, if you read the statement of [Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula), you will find it works for any rectifiable curve. In particular, yes, rectangular paths are fine.

Comment: With arbitrary (rectifiable) curves you have to take the winding number into account.

Comment: If we pick a rectangle, then how does the integral would like? Or it will remain with no changes?

Comment: @mkultra No change.